# Working with JSON object Facebook Graphapi

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, json

I am stuck trying to store values from a JSONObject in a arraylist.

my JSONObject looks like this:

```
 {"id":"112107865788640","friends":{"summary":{"total_count":1},
 "data":[{"id":"111366842530215","name":"James Amigjfihgbjd Alisonsky"}]
 ,"paging":{"next":""}}}, error: null}
```

And i am trying to store the id from data and the name from data in 2 array lists fid and fname.

My code:

```
JSONArray data = object.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length() ; i++){
    fid.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
    fname.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
    Log.v(fid.get(i)," "+fname.get(i));
}
```

But unfortunately i get a error

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for data
```

What am i missing here?

**EDIT**

Tried this now:

```
 JSONObject friends= object.getJSONObject("friends");
 JSONArray data = friends.getJSONArray("data");

 for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length() ; i++){
    JSONObject friend = data.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.v("friend",String.valueOf(friend));
    fid.add(friend.getString("id"));
    fname.add(friend.getString("name"));
    Log.v(fid.get(i)," "+fname.get(i));
 }
```

But i get a null point exception when i try to add them to the array list

friend JSONObject

```
{"id":"111366842530215","name":"James Amigjfihgbjd Alisonsky"}
```

Comment: @BidhanA That is my JSONObject

Comment: Did you get the values in your Log message though?

Comment: @BidhanA log says this {"id":"111366842530215","name":"James Amigjfihgbjd Alisonsky"} for friend object

Comment: So, that means it worked. Your null pointer exception is probably due to some other problem in your code and not related to this particular question.

Comment: @BidhanA Indeed there was another problem i had ArrayList<String> fname instead of ArrayList<String> fname = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `data` is inside of `friends`. Try this

```
JSONObject friends= object.getJSONObject("friends");
JSONArray data = friends.getJSONArray("data");
```